# PSTextFieldSpecifier

Tags: iphone

when i add some text in setting PSTextFieldSpecifier then go to application then changes is not show in the application.but when i closed it and run then change will be there in application.i want sudden change as soon as i close setting i run application.

Comment: After doing Changes save it. it will show in application.

Answer (score 0):

```
    It is recommended that you register any default preference values programmatically at 
launch time in addition to including them in your settings bundle property lists. For newly 
installed applications, default preference values from the application’s settings bundle are 
not set until the Settings application runs. This means that if the user runs your 
application before running Settings, the default values specified in your settings bundle 
will not be available. Setting such values programmatically at launch time ensures that your 
application always has appropriate values. To register default values programmatically, use 
the registerDefaults: method of the NSUserDefaults class.[From apple docs]
```

in your application delegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method write

```
[NSUserDefaults synchronize];
```